# Android não reconhece Mockito NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, mockito

Estou tentando usar Mockito para realizar testes em um aplicativo Android. Copiei os seguintes jars para o projeto: Mockito-all-1.9.5.jar, dexmaker-1.0.jar, dexmaker-Mockito-1.0.jar. Depois adicionei ao BuildPath. Não gera erro de compilação, mas quando rodo os testes, o seguinte erro aparece:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mockito.Mockito
at com.example.projetomockito.test.ClienteTest.testExisteCliente(ClienteTest.java:17)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:545)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1551)
```

O erro aparece na seguinte linha:

```
cliente = mock(Cliente.class);
```

Comment: Você está utilizando Android Studio + Gradle?

Comment: @sicachester, estou usando Eclipse.